# Wrong country of passport issuance on DS-160 Form

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, interview

I submitted an application for a US visa as a Turkish citizen (although I was born and raised in Germany) on a DS-160 Form at the US consulate in Munich, Germany. However, I made a small mistake: when the form asked for the "Country/Authority that Issued Passport/Travel Document:", I answered "Germany" instead of Turkey. I thought I had to choose Germany because I got my Turkish passport from the Turkish Consulate in Germany.

This is already my second amended form, and I don't want to submit a third one. Is this a big problem?

Comment: It kindof is since the country that issued your passport was Turkey and not at all Germany...

Comment: Yes, it's a significant issue. Your application does not correctly state the correct information from your passport. This inconsistentcy will be seen by the visa examiner at the US embassy or consulate, and will likely result in a swift denial of your application.

Comment: Doesn't that count as a minor reckless mistake?  should I submit a 3rd DS-160 form?

Comment: @Pumpkin91 you're telling them that you have a German passport when you actually have a Turkish one... Doesn't seem minor to me.

Comment: Unlike others who are making a big deal of it, in my opinion it’s no big deal. The USA requires an interview and you have an opportunity to correct it there. They will also see your passport and know it’s from Turkey, not Germany. There is no intent to mislead because it is an error which cannot slip them. Relax!

Comment: @Augustine of Hippo ‘An error that cannot slip them’ doesn’t mean it’s an error that may not be seen as an attempt to mislead. There are many questions on this site where an OP has made (to them) a ‘simple oversight’ but still received a refusal. Also many questions on TSE regarding the brevity and inflexibility of the interview for a US visa, with examples where the decision (a refusal) appeared pre-determined irrespective of the interview. If I were the OP I would correct the error *now*, not rely on being given the opportunity to do so during the interview.

Comment: But in the first page, i entered that im Turkish Citizen.

Comment: Were you asked for the country of citizenship, also? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31297/what-is-the-difference-between-country-of-issue-and-country-of-citizenship-o

Comment: Yes, at beginin i was asked about my nationality. I entered turkey

Answer (score 1):

This is a huge mistake.
Correct as soon as possible and hope they had not yet handled the application.

If they think you have mentioned the wrong country on purpose you can face huge problems with not only the USA visa but also visa from other countries.

Comment: Not a huge mistake.

Comment: Claiming to be from a different country is HUGE.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99783/which-country-issued-my-passport-if-i-received-it-at-a-consulate-abroad

Comment: DS-160 are not 'handled' until the interview. There's no reason not to submit another one with the correct informaiton.